# Using virtual directory to host SPA and backend API on same Azure Web App

Tags: angular, spring-boot, iis, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I'm trying to serve my Angular SPA and run the Spring-boot backend API on the same Azure Web app so they share the same domain.

I've created a virtual directory `api/` for running my backend and pointed the root virtual directory to the angular files :
[image: Virtual directory configuration]

I used the default `web.config` in each folder. In backend `wwwroot/api` :

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="MyhttpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
                      arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;D:\home\site\wwwroot\api\my_packaged_api-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar&quot; ">
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And in the angular app folder `wwwroot/dist` :

```xml
<configuration>
       <system.webServer>
          <rewrite>
             <rules>
                <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                   <match url=".*" />
                   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/assets/(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                   </conditions>
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
             </rules>
          </rewrite>
          <staticContent>
             <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
          </staticContent>
       </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

## Problem

API works fine but when I try to access any file from my angular app, I get a 404 from a tomcat server.
When looking in the process started, I see a second Java process started in `wwwroot/dist`. All the 404 end up in this process logs.

[image: lonely java process in spa folder]

Checking the Request Diagnostics I can see that the rewrite rules correctly works and finds my files. But it seems the request is still passed on to this extra tomcat process and returns 404

Is there anything I should change in web.config so it actually returns my files ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with two things in the root web.config in `wwwroot/dist` :

- Avoid inheritance of rewrite rule to child web.config by adding  `inheritInChildApplications="false"`
- Clear handlers and adding a static file handler at the beginning web.config :

```xml
<configuration>
 <location path="."  inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <clear />
         <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The Rémi's answer works for me. But it's good remember that it's necessary close tag location like this

```xml
<configuration>
 <location path="."  inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <clear />
         <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
    ...
 </location>
</configuration>
```

I spent hours looking for what was wrong with my web.config.